# struct type in pyspark groupby and window

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pyspark

What I am trying to do:
Group data based on time intervals (e.g., 15 days window) and perform some operations on dataframe using (pandas) UDFs. I don't know if there is a better/cleaner solution to do it.

Below is the sample code that I tried and error message I am getting.

```
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame([(17.00, "2018-03-10T15:27:18+00:00"),
                            (13.00, "2018-03-11T12:27:18+00:00"),
                            (25.00, "2018-03-12T11:27:18+00:00"),
                            (20.00, "2018-03-13T15:27:18+00:00"),
                            (17.00, "2018-03-14T12:27:18+00:00"),
                            (99.00, "2018-03-15T11:27:18+00:00"),
                            (156.00, "2018-03-22T11:27:18+00:00"),
                            (17.00, "2018-03-31T11:27:18+00:00"),
                            (25.00, "2018-03-15T11:27:18+00:00"),
                            (25.00, "2018-03-16T11:27:18+00:00")
                            ],
                           ["id", "ts"])
df = df.withColumn('ts', df.ts.cast('timestamp'))

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("ts", TimestampType())
])


@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def some_udf(df):
    # some computation
    return df

df.groupby('id', F.window("ts", "15 days")).apply(some_udf).show()
```

This throws following exception:

```
TypeError: Unsupported type in conversion from Arrow: struct<start: timestamp[us, tz=America/Chicago], end: timestamp[us, tz=America/Chicago]>
```

[This bug reports is related to return type of struct and missing params in pandas udaf. It doesn't answer my question.](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23883)

However, if I use builtin agg method then it works all fine. For example,

```
df.groupby('id', F.window("ts", "15 days")).mean().show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----+------------------------------------------+-------+
|id   |window                                    |avg(id)|
+-----+------------------------------------------+-------+
|13.0 |[2018-03-05 00:00:00, 2018-03-20 00:00:00]|13.0   |
|17.0 |[2018-03-20 00:00:00, 2018-04-04 00:00:00]|17.0   |
|156.0|[2018-03-20 00:00:00, 2018-04-04 00:00:00]|156.0  |
|99.0 |[2018-03-05 00:00:00, 2018-03-20 00:00:00]|99.0   |
|20.0 |[2018-03-05 00:00:00, 2018-03-20 00:00:00]|20.0   |
|17.0 |[2018-03-05 00:00:00, 2018-03-20 00:00:00]|17.0   |
|25.0 |[2018-03-05 00:00:00, 2018-03-20 00:00:00]|25.0   |
+-----+------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp type object in Pandas could only be generated from pure string with structure like this:

```
'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

The order of YMD or HMS can be set. If you want to add timezone info, you could only set it with this:

```
df.Timestamp(tz = 'your timezone')
```

You can't write timezone info into the string that you want to convert to Timestamp type, or it will not be interpreted by Timestamp() type-converter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't answer my question. I get the same error independent of timezone info. pandas' UDAF is giving error as it is not recognizing "window" column with struct type. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is still relevant but I leave my answer here in case it will help somebody else.

I had to use Pyspark 2.3.2 and I ran into the same issue. I also needed to use the window start and end dates in pandas calculations for interpolation of missing dates.

The only way I found to deal with this was to add the window.start and window.end to the dataframe first and then pass that to pandas. Here is an example:

```
from pyspark import sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
from pyspark.sql import functions as F                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
from pyspark.sql.types import (IntegerType, StructField, StructType,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                               TimestampType)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
sparkSession = sql.SparkSession.builder \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        .appName("local-spark-session") \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        .getOrCreate()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame([(17.00, "2018-03-10T15:27:18+00:00"), (13.00, "2018-03-11T12:27:18+00:00"),                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                   (25.00, "2018-03-12T11:27:18+00:00"), (20.00, "2018-03-13T15:27:18+00:00"),                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                   (17.00, "2018-03-14T12:27:18+00:00"), (99.00, "2018-03-15T11:27:18+00:00"),                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                   (156.00, "2018-03-22T11:27:18+00:00"), (17.00, "2018-03-31T11:27:18+00:00"),                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                   (25.00, "2018-03-15T11:27:18+00:00"), (25.00, "2018-03-16T11:27:18+00:00")],                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                  ["id", "ts"])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
df = df.withColumn('ts', df.ts.cast('timestamp'))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType()), StructField("ts", TimestampType())])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
@F.pandas_udf(schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
def some_udf(df):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    import os                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    os.environ['ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT'] = '1'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    # some computation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    return df[['id', 'ts']]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
df = df.withColumn("window", F.window("ts", "15 days")) \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    .withColumn("window_start", F.col("window").start) \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    .withColumn("window_end", F.col("window").end) \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    .drop(F.col("window"))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
df.show(truncate=False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
df.groupby('id', 'window_start', 'window_end').apply(some_udf).show(truncate=False)
```

This dataframe modified dataframe (first call to df.show())

```
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+             
|id   |ts                 |window_start       |window_end         |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|17.0 |2018-03-10 16:27:18|2018-03-05 01:00:00|2018-03-20 01:00:00|
|13.0 |2018-03-11 13:27:18|2018-03-05 01:00:00|2018-03-20 01:00:00|
|25.0 |2018-03-12 12:27:18|2018-03-05 01:00:00|2018-03-20 01:00:00|
|20.0 |2018-03-13 16:27:18|2018-03-05 01:00:00|2018-03-20 01:00:00|
|17.0 |2018-03-14 13:27:18|2018-03-05 01:00:00|2018-03-20 01:00:00|
|99.0 |2018-03-15 12:27:18|2018-03-05 01:00:00|2018-03-20 01:00:00|
|156.0|2018-03-22 12:27:18|2018-03-20 01:00:00|2018-04-04 02:00:00|
|17.0 |2018-03-31 13:27:18|2018-03-20 01:00:00|2018-04-04 02:00:00|
|25.0 |2018-03-15 12:27:18|2018-03-05 01:00:00|2018-03-20 01:00:00|
|25.0 |2018-03-16 12:27:18|2018-03-05 01:00:00|2018-03-20 01:00:00|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

And the output of panda udf

```
+---+-------------------+                                                       
|id |ts                 |
+---+-------------------+
|13 |2018-03-11 13:27:18|
|17 |2018-03-31 13:27:18|
|156|2018-03-22 12:27:18|
|99 |2018-03-15 12:27:18|
|20 |2018-03-13 16:27:18|
|17 |2018-03-10 16:27:18|
|17 |2018-03-14 13:27:18|
|25 |2018-03-12 12:27:18|
|25 |2018-03-15 12:27:18|
|25 |2018-03-16 12:27:18|
+---+-------------------+
```